# How to change color of drawn points on pyGal line chart

Tags: python, pygal

I am creating a line graph using pygal by passing in an array of numbers to be graphed. I am wishing for the points marked on the graph to change color when they are in/outside of a certain range. I.e. If there is a point logged over 40, color it red, if there is a point logged under 20, color it blue.

There does not seem to be an easy way to loop through the array and draw a single point.

The graph is being made with the following code:

```
    customStyle = Style(colors=["#000000"])
    chart = pygal.Line(style=customStyle)
    chart.title = 'Browser usage evolution (in %)'
    chart.x_labels = recordedDates
    chart.add('Humidity', recordedHumidity)
    chart.render_to_png("out.png")
```

I would like to have all points above 40 red and below 20 blue.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace a number in the array with a `dict` that tells Pygal how to render the data point.  This `dict` must contain the key `value`, which is the number you would have passed, alongside any customisation options you want to use.  The list of available options is provided on [the value configuration page of the docs](http://pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/configuration/value.html), but the one you need here is `color`.

You can simply iterate over your existing array, creating a dictionary where `color` is set appropriately for the value:

```
data = []
for v in recordedHumidity:
    if v > 40:
        data.append({"value": v, "color": "red"})
    elif v < 20:
        data.append({"value": v, "color": "blue"})
    else:
        data.append(v)
```

You can then pass the newly created array when adding the series:

```
customStyle = Style(colors=["#000000"])
chart = pygal.Line(style=customStyle)
chart.x_labels = recordedDates
chart.add('Humidity', data)
chart.render_to_png("out.png")
```

[image: Example chart with different coloured dots]

You might also want to look at the [chart configuration](http://pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/configuration/chart.html) and [series configuration](http://pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/configuration/serie.html) pages in the docs to see how to customise other aspects of the chart, such as the size of the markers.